# Is there any difference between "post" and "position"?

Tags: meaning, differences

I know that both *post* and *position* are polysemic and have a lot of non-overlapping meanings, but I am asking about the following definitions:

> **position:** a post of employment: *a position in a bank*.
>
> **post:** a position of duty, employment, or trust to which one is assigned or appointed: *a diplomatic post*.

In this meanig, are these two words completely interchangeable or are there any slight differences in the meaning? The question arose when I wrote

> [He] applied for the position of head of human resources at [a big company].

and my teacher corrected *position* to *post*. When I asked her why, she just said that in that particular context *post* sounded right and *position* sounded wrong (to her British ears).

So, what is the difference between *post* and *position* and why (if my teacher is right) is *post* preferable to *position* in my sample sentence?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While *position* and *post* can often be used interchangeably in reference to employment or occupation, I believe

- *Post* more strongly connotes an assigned station, especially a specific geographic place and often for a temporary or rotating assignment.
- *Position* on the other hand more strongly connotes a rank or class.

In my experience, if you ask an executive for her post, she may say "the Lisbon office," whereas if you ask for her "position," she's more likely to say "Vice President for Ibero-European Operations" or some such.

Both *position* and *post* can trace their roots back to the Latin verb *pono, ponere*, meaning to put or to situate something, but the latter, [according to Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/post?show=2&t=1333038175), came via Middle French and Old Italian having acquired the meaning of a relay station along the way. This sense of *post* is of course carried through in its courier-related meanings, i.e. we send mail through the post (NAmE) or send a post through the mail (BrE).

The U.S. Army refers generically to its installations as "posts," and a soldier is "posted" to a particular assignment as well as given a particular "post" when on duty. In the same way we can speak of journalists or diplomats being sent to a "post" like the Tehran bureau or the Shanghai consulate or of waitresses or warehouse workers being sent to a "post" like tables 20-24 or delivery dock C. In both cases, we are speaking of a temporary assignment to a particular station.

So in your example, I would think either of

> [He] applied for the position of head of human resources at [a big company].
>
> [He] applied for the post of head of human resources at [a big company].

to be fine, the former preferred if "head of human resources" is a permanent role, the latter if it's a waystation for those on their way up or down the corporate ladder.

Answer (score 5):

It is totally subjective, but one difference in usage that I can sense is the following. *Post* is commoner when one applies for a job, *position* sounds good when you talk of someone who is settled in his job.

For example,

- This job is posted in London.
- My job posted me to London.
- His position as a senior manager came under scrutiny.

The exchange of post/position in these sentences will cause them to sound rather awkward.

Answer (score 3):

In American English anyway, I think in this context the two words are synonyms. Most would say "position" except for a few stock phrases, like "diplomatic post".

Answer (score 1):

It is purely cultural. Both can be interchanged freely so long as you retain consistent use of one or the other to prevent confusion.

> He was *posted to/positioned in* the *post/position* of Manager.

Comment: You have to be careful using 'position' as a verb. It's often used in a business context, and possibly more widely, to describe the strategies which individuals or organisations use to gain a commercial or some other advantage.